# Variations of an exam

Tags: exam

I'm using the great [exam package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam) to create exams. But sometimes there are many students so I need to create different "versions" - `Group A` and `Group B`.

Mainly the differences are only the numbers in questions so the text of questions are similar. Now I do the follow:

- create a command named `\finalexam` which has the questions with macros (`\question[5] What is the result of $\a\cdot\b$`)
- create the macros (`\def\a{10}`, `\def\b{20}`)
- call `\finalexam`
- change the macros (`\def\a{20}`, `def\b{30}`)
- call `\finalexam`

Is there any other (better) solution or a ready-to-use package?

**Edit**: a simple example

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\pagestyle{empty}
\addpoints
\pointname{ pont}
\pointsinrightmargin
\marginpointname{ pont}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\doga}{
\centerline{\large V. exam -- \group\ group}
\begin{questions}
    \question[5]What is the result of $\a\cdot\b$?
\end{questions}}
%
\newcommand{\group}{A}
\renewcommand{\a}{5}
\renewcommand{\b}{10}
\doga
%
\renewcommand{\group}{B}
\renewcommand{\a}{10}
\renewcommand{\b}{20}
\doga
\end{document}
```

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) which those trying to help cam adapt to yield a better solution for you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`mailmerge`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mailmerge) and declare some fields (`\mailfields`), define the repetitions (`\mailrepeat`) and define different sets of parameters (`\mailentry`).

See the documentation for persuasive examples.

**Edit:**
Here's your example with `mailmerge`:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mailmerge}
\pagestyle{empty}
\addpoints
\pointname{ pont}
\pointsinrightmargin
\marginpointname{ pont}
\begin{document}
\mailfields{group,a,b}
\mailrepeat{
\centerline{\large V. exam -- \field{group} group}
\begin{questions}
    \question[5]What is the result of $\field{a}\cdot\field{b}$?
\end{questions}\clearpage}
\mailentry{A,5,10}
\mailentry{B,10,20}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm, it seems very good :) I'm waiting more answers.

Answer (score 13):

This question is the reason for the »variations« feature of [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) introduced in v0.6. The command `\vary` is provided which in the default setting has two arguments. The command `\variant{<num>}` (where `<num>` is either `1` or `2`) will choose if the first or second argument is used.

Here is a use-case example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usepackage[load-headings]{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{
  headings = runin-nr ,
  headings-format = \normalfont ,
  points/name = pont/ok % this is what translate.google.com tells me...
}

\begin{document}

% \variant{1} % default
\centerline{\large V. exam -- \vary{A}{B} group}
\bigskip

\begin{question}{5}
 What is the result of $\vary{5}{10}\cdot\vary{10}{20}$?
\end{question}

\bigskip
\variant{2}
\centerline{\large V. exam -- \vary{A}{B} group}
\bigskip

\begin{question}{5}
 What is the result of $\vary{5}{10}\cdot\vary{10}{20}$?
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wanted more than two variations you could for example issue `\SetVariations{3}` in the preamble which would cause `\vary` to have three arguments. `<num>` in `\variant{<num>}` now could be `1`, `2` or `3`.

Comment: Wow! Very-very impressive :) Next year I'll try it (I hope pupils will be happy :) )

Comment: (In hungarian language we don't use plural in quantities, so we say "5 point" not "5 points", translate: "5 pont", not "5 pontok")

Comment: @uzsolt I see. In this case simply use `points/name=pont`.

Comment: This solution is very good, I've switched your `exsheets` package.

Comment: @uzsolt glad you like it :)

Comment: kinly give link to download multiplechoicequestion.sty. i couldnot get it... please@cgnieder

Comment: @David I have never heard of any `multiplechoicequestion.sty` before!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your problem is solved by the (brand new) [exsheets package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets)?  Questions can be assigned classes and you can select what classes to show...

Comment: It seems very impressive. But (as I see) I can't do what I want: same questions with different datas. If it's possible I don't want type any text twice if it doesn't need. Please see Hasan Zakeri's answer.

Or can I do it?

Comment: @uzsolt It can't right now. I might add something, though.

Comment: @cgnieder do you are the developer? :) I'm waiting about this. Do you accept "feature requests"? :)

Comment: @uzsolt I am :) You can report issues and make requests at the bitbucket site or send me an email. Both addresses are mentioned in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Compile with LuaTeX and define a macro that returns either the text for variation A or variation B. That allows you to edit the variations in place. Same syntax as with `\vary` with exsheets. You have to manually switch between the variations though and compile twice.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass [11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={16cm, 26cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% defines a command for the variations
% change to variation B by replacing '#1' with '#2'
\newcommand{\var}[2]{\luadirect{tex.sprint('#1')}}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question Boris throws two six-sided dices.
\begin{parts}
\part[2] Compute the Probability that \var{both dices display 6}{the results of both diced add up to 12}.
\vspace{3cm}
\part[3] Compute the probability that at least one of the dices shows a \var{1}{2}.
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```