# Mailmerge alternatives for exam variations?

Tags: exam

I need to make 10 different versions of a test for a very large cohort of students.  I could use mailmerge for this, but I wonder if there are any alternatives which might suit my needs better?

For example, test 1 might have

```
\int_0^1 x e^{x^2}\,dx
```

and test 2 (for the same question) might have

```
\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/2}x\cos(x^2)\,dx
```

and so on.  Clearly I would need to set up some sort of external file containing all the variations, and have that read into the main file, to produce the different tests.  What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57012/variations-of-an-exam/57021

Comment: I don't know whether it's the best option, but there are tools for doing mailmerge-like tasks that (imho) work better than the mailmerge package. For example [this](https://github.com/adrianN/latex-mailmerge) uses Python and CVS files to generate documents.

Comment: I'm seeing this as a dupe at the moment.