# Hacking into (internal) references in exam class

Tags: macros, exam

So far, I have used my homebrewn style file to create the examination papers which have multiple sets of questions.

Recently, I switched to the [`exam`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam) class and immensely enjoying the additional power it provides. Now, in case of multiple sets, I am stuck at some point.

My setup, with all the paraphernalia striped, looks something like this.
I use the macro `\setcode` which, along with other
things, control the inclusion of external files and use of fonts at specific places.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\begin{document}

\def\setcode{1}
Total: \numpoints
\begin{questions}
  \question[5] First question in Set 1.
\end{questions}

\def\setcode{2}
Total: \numpoints
\begin{questions}
  \question[5] First question in Set 2.
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Now, the problem with the above scenario is, internals like `\numpoints` are incorrect. As is evidenced by the output and the warning  message
regarding multiply defined labels.

I found out that the labels are no more handled using `\label`s. Rather,
these are written directly into the .aux file. See this excerpt from 
`exam.cls`.

> This was previously done with `\pageref` commands.  When I stopped 
>   using `\pageref` for this (in order to make this compatible with 
>   `hyperref.sty`), this stuff was created:
>
> `\gdef` commands for `exam@lastpage`, `exam@numpoints`, 
>   `exam@numbonuspoints`, `exam@numquestions`, `exam@numparts`, 
>   `exam@numsubparts` and `exam@numsubsubparts` are written to the `.aux` 
>   file via `\AtEndDocument`.

I understand that if I could hack my `\setcode` into the above internals,
my problem would have been solved.

Do you think you could suggest a way for this?

I know that a completely new setup, say something [like this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57012/variations-of-an-exam), perhaps 
would solve my problem. But the other side of the coin is, I  already have a big setup
from more than a decade, which will have to be completely reworked in 
order for the new setup to work.

Comment: My first impression: I wouldn't do that if I were you. The class is quite well designed for smaller elements (parts, subparts, subsubparts), but not the other way around. Even if you touch the code and add prefix where needed, everything is stored in the `aux` file and that would require additional rewritting of the code, a simple setting of the parameters wouldn't help. I would prepare one TeX file on a per student basis (generated from the database somehow, perhaps), that is a sort of workaround for this class. Or I would try the `eqexam` package (AcroTeX bundle) if it fits my needs better.

Comment: @Malipivo The `eqexam` looks like a promising one, and perhaps will solve my problem, again, with a major reworking of my present setup. So, I will take your first advice, use my setup, fitted into `exam` class. At the same time, I will want keep the uses of internal counters minimal.

Comment: I am thinking about two scenarios: if there is a way of storing those key counters by ourselves (let's say a series of `\label`s or `\let`s), then there would be no need for that `aux` file at all, or, if there is a way of loading and saving the `aux` file intentionally on-the-fly (that's usually unrecommended way).

Comment: @Malipivo I was thinking of the first way and was looking into the cls file to identify the corresponding labels, so that I can append the set code to the labels. I hit a wall when I read the portion excerpted in my original question.

Comment: I have started with chasing the counters. `:-)` `\def\catchme{exam@numquestions:
\thenumquestions\par
exam@numparts:
\thenumparts\par
exam@numsubparts:
\thenumsubparts\par
exam@numsubsubparts:
\thenumsubsubparts} \catchme`

Answer (score 1):

> An experiment (partly solved based on comments)

I am not done, but I am presenting my findings for the other solvers to save some time. Below is my patch/style file catching and clearing most of the counters. Unresolved problems are:

- Points and bonus points of an individual question, if they are needed. `\pointsofq@` and `\bonuspointsofq@` of question `i`, `ii` etc.
- Also basic staff like last page of the exam is missing. It only requires `\label` with a unique marker, e.g. a counter of exams.
- How to unload the content of the `\AtEndDocument{}` command without touching the `exam.cls` file, e.g. by deleting that portion of code. The reason is that we dislike that warning about multiply defined labels.
- To actually catch the counters by `\label`s for instance and loading them back by `\ref` or `\pageref`. This experiment is listing the values but we cannot use them at the beginning or in the middle of the actual exam.
- Are there any more counters in that class? `:-)`

This is the `mal-patch.sty` file with two commands, the `\catchme` is calling for `\clearme` automatically, but I tried to separate these two tasks from each other.

```
\makeatletter

%\newcounter{pageof@pagepoints}
%\newcounter{pageof@pagebonuspoints}


\def\clearme{
\setcounter{numquestions}{0}
\setcounter{numparts}{0}
\setcounter{numsubparts}{0}
\setcounter{numsubsubparts}{0}
%
\set@hlfcntr{numpoints}{0}
\set@hlfcntr{numbonuspoints}{0}
\set@hlfcntr{pointsof@thisquestion}{0}
\set@hlfcntr{bonuspointsof@thisquestion}{0}
%
\set@hlfcntr{@pagepoints}{0}
\set@hlfcntr{@pagebonuspoints}{0}
\setcounter{pageof@pagepoints}{0}
\setcounter{pageof@pagebonuspoints}{0}
%
\set@hlfcntr{latest@points}{0}
\set@hlfcntr{latest@bonuspoints}{0}
}% End of \clearme...


\def\catchme{\indent\par
numquestions: \thenumquestions\par
numparts: \thenumparts\par
numsubparts: \thenumsubparts\par
numsubsubparts: \thenumsubsubparts\par
%
numpoints: \prtaux@hlfcntr{numpoints}\par
numbonuspoints: \prtaux@hlfcntr{numbonuspoints}\par
pointsofthisquestion: \prtaux@hlfcntr{pointsof@thisquestion}\par
bonuspointsofthisquestion: \prtaux@hlfcntr{bonuspointsof@thisquestion}\par
%
pagepoints: \prtaux@hlfcntr{@pagepoints}\par
pagebonuspoints: \prtaux@hlfcntr{@pagebonuspoints}\par
pageofpagepoints: \thepageof@pagepoints\par
pageofpagebonuspoints: \thepageof@pagebonuspoints\par
%
latestpoints: \prtaux@hlfcntr{latest@points}\par
latestbonuspoints: \prtaux@hlfcntr{latest@bonuspoints}\par
\clearme % before another set of questions...
}% End of \catchme...

\makeatother
```

And this is how to use it so far from the `mal-exam.tex` file:

```
%! *latex mal-exam.tex
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{mal-patch}

\begin{document}
\def\setcode{1}
\begin{questions}
  \question[5] First question in Set \setcode.
\end{questions}
\catchme
%%% Next set of questions...
\def\setcode{2}
\begin{questions}
  \question[5] First question in Set \setcode.
\end{questions}
\catchme
\end{document}
```

[image: mnwe]