# How to create a exam with the student's name using auto-multiple-choice?

Tags: latex-misc, auto-multiple-choice

I would like to load the student's list (names and ID's) and generate a exam for each one with the ID number already selected/marked. Could anyone create an minimal example of this?

The correction of the exam would also will use the same student's list.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Does one of the solutions to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57012/15925 help?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I wish to use the integration with auto-multiple-choice (http://home.gna.org/auto-qcm/). The solution above is for the exam package and others. Thanks.

Comment: Does this program output latex or pdf?  Do you seriously expect anyone here to be using this program?

Comment: There are others questions about Auto-Multiple-Choice (AMC) package/software in this forum. The source code used is a .tex file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the *7.3 Nominative sheets* section in the [documentation](http://home.gna.org/auto-qcm/auto-multiple-choice.en/alt.shtml#Nominative.sheets), and [this full sample](https://bitbucket.org/auto-multiple-choice/auto-multiple-choice/src/default/tests/t/preassociation/source.tex) using the `csvsimple` package.